# Neo4j shortestPath cypher with a relation property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database with nodes (Tiles) connected with relations (Connects). Both tiles and relations have a property called blocked. I would like to get a shortest path between 2 nodes without it containing a blocked node or relation. So when that blocked property is true, that node/relation is not to be used when finding a shortest path. 
The problem I am struggling with is at the relation when i try to filter them on that property.

For example when I try:

```
MATCH (node1:Tile {x :1, y :1, blocked:false}),(node2:Tile {x: 2, y: 4, blocked:false}),
p = shortestPath((node1)-[:Connects {blocked:false}]-(node2)) 
RETURN p
```

I get the error:

```
shortestPath(...) contains properties MapExpression(List((PropertyKeyName(blocked),False()))). This is currently not supported. (line 2, column 5 (offset: 93))
"p = shortestPath((node1)-[:Connects {blocked:false}]-(node2))"
```

So my question is: Did I get the cypher wrong, or am I really trying something that is not supported. And ofcourse, what would be the best solution to this puzzle?

Comment: As the error message is telling you, you cannot currently use properties (`{blocked:false}`) within the `shortestPath` call.

Comment: Ok, that means I didn't get the cypher wrong. I will try it without the shortestPath method than. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should select all paths which have a "blocked" flag cleared. You'll probably want to tweak the [:Connects*] relationship to a reasonable limit.

```
MATCH (node1:Tile {x :1, y :1, blocked:false}),
      (node2:Tile {x: 2, y: 4, blocked:false}),
      p = shortestPath((node1)-[:Connects*]-(node2)) 
WHERE ALL (x IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE x.blocked = FALSE)
RETURN p
```

Comment: p becomes the shortest path in graph, and the WHERE ALL () phrase traverses the path's relationships to ensure that all the relationship "blocked" properties are set to FALSE. If any of them are TRUE, then the graph is rejected.

Comment: My final solution based on your answer to also have not blocked nodes: 


MATCH (node1:Tile {x :1, y :1}), (node2:Tile {x: 8, y: 6}),

      p = shortestPath((node1)-[:Connects*]-(node2)) 

WHERE ALL (x IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE x.blocked = FALSE)

AND ALL (y IN NODES(p) WHERE y.blocked = FALSE)
RETURN p



I will play a little with the limit on Connects.

Comment: If blocked is on the nodes and relationships the "x in p" may also work.